# Is there any way to find out the range of time before and after daylight savings in C#?

Tags: c#, timezone, utc, dst, timezone-offset

There are plenty of options available in `TimeZoneInfo` class to find out current server time UTC offset, if the time is daylight saving time or not etc.

But is there any way to find out the ranges of daylight saving time for a given date range

So basically say if the timezone offset for any server during the year considering daylight saving is

```
Mar-Oct - UTC-4
Nov-Feb - UCT-5
```

And if I pass the range as `Jan-Jun` then the output that I am looking for is this

```
Jan-Feb   - UTC-5
Mar-Jun   - UTC-4
```

I have checked below methods and properties in a try to make, but not able to get the desired output in optimal way

```
TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset.Hours

TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime
```

Comment: `UTC-4` isn't a timezone, it's an offset. You can use [TimeZoneInfo.GetAdjustmentRules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.getadjustmentrules?view=netcore-3.1) to get a timezone's rules

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Corrected

Comment: No, the error remains. You *can't* get any daytime rules for an *offset* because there aren't any. There's no UTC-4 timezone. There are Easter European, Pacific, or Indian timezones, whose *offsets* change from eg `UTC-4` to `UTC-5` based on the timezone's or even country's rules.

Comment: The documentation example for the [TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.adjustmentrule?view=netcore-3.1) prints all rules for all TimeZoneInfo objects registered on a machine. That includes both actual timezones and fixed offsets like `UTC-4`. The TZ information on Windows is a bit .... disorganized

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Yes, but the daylight saving changes the timezone or the offset of the same county or region, so basically we have two different offset for same region in different time, no?

Comment: No. The timezone is the same - Pacific Standard Time, or Pakistan Standard Time. The countries may have the same longitude, but different timezones and adjustment rules, that result in different offsets for the same timezone. In fact, that's what your question is about. `UTC-4` is used in Windows to represent an *offset* not a timezone. The countries intersected by that offset all have very different timezones and rules

Comment: In fact, if you check the Wikipedia entry for [UTC-04:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9204:00) you'll see that different countries use it at different times, and some, like Suriname, don't use it even though they're 100% in that region

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) to solve this.  (Sure, you could use `TimeZoneInfo` but processing adjustment rules are a pain.)

Declare these imports:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using NodaTime;
```

Define a function to do the main work:

```cs
static (LocalDateTime StartDateTime, LocalDateTime UntilDateTime, Offset UtcOffset)[] 
    GetOffsetRanges(DateTimeZone tz, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate untilDate)
{
    // Get ZonedDateTime values representing the start of day of each date in the given time zone.
    ZonedDateTime startZonedDateTime = startDate.AtStartOfDayInZone(tz);
    ZonedDateTime untilZonedDateTime = untilDate.AtStartOfDayInZone(tz);

    // We'll also need the corresponding Instant of each value.
    Instant startInstant = startZonedDateTime.ToInstant();
    Instant untilInstant = untilZonedDateTime.ToInstant();

    // Get the ZoneInterval values, which tell us the range that an offset is in effect.
    return tz.GetZoneIntervals(startInstant, untilInstant).Select(interval =>
    {
        // Snap the values to the range we're working with.  (This is optional, you could just use the IsoLocalStart/End values directly.)
        LocalDateTime startDateTime = interval.Start >= startInstant ? interval.IsoLocalStart : startZonedDateTime.LocalDateTime;
        LocalDateTime untilDateTime = interval.End <= untilInstant ? interval.IsoLocalEnd : untilZonedDateTime.LocalDateTime;

        // Include the local date and time range, and the offset that's in effect over that range.
        return (startDateTime, untilDateTime, interval.WallOffset);

    }).ToArray();
}
```

Use the function like so:

```cs
// Define your input values
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/New_York"];
var startDate = new LocalDate(2020, 1, 1);
var untilDate = new LocalDate(2021, 1, 1);

// Call the function to get the ranges
var ranges = GetOffsetRanges(tz, startDate, untilDate);

// Example output
Console.WriteLine($"Offsets in {tz.Id} between {startDate:R} and {untilDate:R} are as follows:");
foreach (var range in ranges)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{range.StartDateTime:s} - {range.UntilDateTime:s} : {range.UtcOffset:m}");
}
```

Output:

```
Offsets in America/New_York between 2020-01-01 and 2021-01-01 are as follows:
2020-01-01T00:00:00 - 2020-03-08T02:00:00 : -05:00
2020-03-08T03:00:00 - 2020-11-01T02:00:00 : -04:00
2020-11-01T01:00:00 - 2021-01-01T00:00:00 : -05:00
```

A few notes:

- I don't recommend simplifying the input or output in the way you stated in your question.  It is not precise enough to say `Mar-Oct`.
- As Panagiotis pointed out in the question comments, you will need to identify a *time zone* to use.  A single offset input is not sufficient.  My example showed a named IANA time zone, but if desired you could instead pass the system's local time zone by using `DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault()`
- If this is going to run on a *server*, then please don't use the system's local time zone.  In general, the server's time zone should be considered *irrelevant*.
- In a web application, you can get the user's IANA time zone identifier in JavaScript with `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`.  You can pass that to your server and use it as input with the above code.  (This works on most modern web browsers, but not all older ones.)